Difference of mem::take and mem::swap leading to kernel panic Rust
With the below context (Rust Windows driver), I have highlighted the mem::swap with a comment:
use core::mem;

pub struct DriverMessagesWithMutex {
    lock: FAST_MUTEX,
    is_empty: bool,
    data: DriverMessages,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default, Debug)]
struct DriverMessages {
    messages: Vec<String>,
    process_creations: Vec<ProcessStarted>,
}

impl Default for DriverMessagesWithMutex {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let mut mutex = FAST_MUTEX::default();
        unsafe { ExInitializeFastMutex(&mut mutex) };
        let data = DriverMessages::default();

        DriverMessagesWithMutex { lock: mutex, is_empty: true, data }
    }
}

impl DriverMessagesWithMutex {
    // ..

    /// Adds a print msg to the queue.
    /// 
    /// This function will wait for an acquisition of the spin lock to continue and will block
    /// until that point.
    pub fn add_message_to_queue(&mut self, data: String)
     {

        let irql = unsafe { KeGetCurrentIrql() };
        if irql != 0 {
            println!("[sanctum] [-] IRQL is not PASSIVE_LEVEL: {}", irql);
            return;
        }

        unsafe { ExAcquireFastMutex(&mut self.lock) };

        let irql = unsafe { KeGetCurrentIrql() };
        if irql > APC_LEVEL as u8 {
            println!("[sanctum] [-] IRQL is not APIC_LEVEL: {}", irql);
            unsafe { ExReleaseFastMutex(&mut self.lock) }; 
            return;
        }

        self.is_empty = false;
        self.data.messages.push(data);

        unsafe { ExReleaseFastMutex(&mut self.lock) }; 
    }


    /// Adds data of type ProcessStarted to the message queue.
    /// 
    /// This function will wait for an acquisition of the spin lock to continue and will block
    /// until that point.
    pub fn add_process_creation_to_queue(&mut self, data: ProcessStarted)
     {

        let irql = unsafe { KeGetCurrentIrql() };
        if irql != 0 {
            println!("[sanctum] [-] IRQL is not PASSIVE_LEVEL: {}", irql);
            return;
        }

        unsafe { ExAcquireFastMutex(&mut self.lock) };

        let irql = unsafe { KeGetCurrentIrql() };
        if irql > APC_LEVEL as u8 {
            println!("[sanctum] [-] IRQL is not APIC_LEVEL: {}", irql);
            unsafe { ExReleaseFastMutex(&mut self.lock) }; 
            return;
        }

        self.is_empty = false;
        self.data.process_creations.push(data);
        
        unsafe { ExReleaseFastMutex(&mut self.lock) }; 
    }

    fn extract_all(&mut self) -> Option<DriverMessages> {

        let irql = unsafe { KeGetCurrentIrql() };
        if irql != 0 {
            println!("[sanctum] [-] IRQL is not PASSIVE_LEVEL: {}", irql);
            return None;
        }

        unsafe { ExAcquireFastMutex(&mut self.lock) };

        let irql = unsafe { KeGetCurrentIrql() };
        if irql > APC_LEVEL as u8 {
            println!("[sanctum] [-] IRQL is not APIC_LEVEL: {}", irql);
            unsafe { ExReleaseFastMutex(&mut self.lock) }; 
            return None;
        }

        if self.is_empty {
            unsafe { ExReleaseFastMutex(&mut self.lock) }; 
            return None;
        }
        
        // THIS PART HERE
        let mut extracted_data = DriverMessages::default();
        mem::swap(&mut extracted_data, &mut self.data);
        self.is_empty = true; // reset flag

        unsafe { ExReleaseFastMutex(&mut self.lock) }; 

        Some(extracted_data)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct ProcessStarted {
    pub image_name: String,
    pub command_line: String,
    pub parent_pid: String,
}

// Windows sys crate for driver development:

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub unsafe fn ExInitializeFastMutex(kmutex: *mut FAST_MUTEX) {
    core::ptr::write_volatile(&mut (*kmutex).Count, FM_LOCK_BIT as i32);

    (*kmutex).Owner = core::ptr::null_mut();
    (*kmutex).Contention = 0;
    KeInitializeEvent(&mut (*kmutex).Event, SynchronizationEvent, FALSE as _)
}

I am looking to return out the content of self.data in a memory efficient way (avoiding a clone()) so that a caching structure in the kernel can take ownership of a cached view to do with it as it pleases.
When using mem::take() instead of mem::swap(), a blue screen kernel panic was happening each time; and I'm trying to figure the internals out for my own learning.
The rust docs say:

Take allows taking ownership of a struct field by replacing it with an “empty” value.

This seems to be the exact same thing as using mem::replace. The only thing I can think of is somehow a part of the kernel is trying to access / write to the memory at self.data, at the time of the operation? Or that memory was deemed valid but has now been invalidated after the take operation - but in both cases, should it not work the same as mem::swap()?
I would be grateful for an explanation as to the differences between these functions, and whether the context of running in the kernel makes a difference to the assurance against panics using these functions.
To provide context as to how the struct is used, I have two static global variables (which I know is not a good rust pattern) for holding the 'live' and cached DriverMessagesWithMutex data:
// delcared
static DRIVER_MESSAGES: AtomicPtr<DriverMessagesWithMutex> = AtomicPtr::new(null_mut());
static DRIVER_MESSAGES_CACHE: AtomicPtr<DriverMessagesWithMutex> = AtomicPtr::new(null_mut());

// initialised like so:
let messages = Box::new(DriverMessagesWithMutex::new());
let messages_cache = Box::new(DriverMessagesWithMutex::new());
DRIVER_MESSAGES.store(Box::into_raw(messages), Ordering::SeqCst);
DRIVER_MESSAGES_CACHE.store(Box::into_raw(messages_cache), Ordering::SeqCst);

These are global, as in the driver I am using callback functions to kernel events to log data, these callbacks only accept a function pointer (i.e. I cannot pass a RC/ARC into them), for instance PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx:
PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(Some(core_callback_notify_ps), FALSE as u8);

Within the core_callback_notify_ps function, I access the global DRIVER_MESSAGES like so:
pub unsafe extern "C" fn core_callback_notify_ps(process: PEPROCESS, pid: HANDLE, created: *mut PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO) {

    if !created.is_null() {

        let image_name = unicode_to_string((*created).ImageFileName);
        let command_line = unicode_to_string((*created).CommandLine);
        let ppid = format!("{:?}", (*created).ParentProcessId);

        if image_name.is_err() || command_line.is_err() {
            return;
        }

        let process_started = ProcessStarted {
            image_name: image_name.unwrap().replace("\\??\\", ""),
            command_line: command_line.unwrap().replace("\\??\\", ""),
            parent_pid: ppid,
        };
        
        
        // Attempt to dereference the DRIVER_MESSAGES global; if the dereference is successful,
        // add the relevant data to the queue
        if !DRIVER_MESSAGES.load(Ordering::SeqCst).is_null() {
            let obj = unsafe { &mut *DRIVER_MESSAGES.load(Ordering::SeqCst) };
            obj.add_process_creation_to_queue(process_started);
        } else {
            println!("[sanctum] [-] Driver messages is null");
        }; 
    }
}

I am then trying to read from the globals like so:
if !DRIVER_MESSAGES.load(Ordering::SeqCst).is_null() {
    let original_object = unsafe { &mut *DRIVER_MESSAGES.load(Ordering::SeqCst) };

    // drained would then be copied into the cache if empty, or appended if not empty
    let drained = original_object.extract_all();
}


I'm not a kernel expert and you didn't provide a MRE, but using &mut for mutex seems wrong and UB.

@ChayimFriedman Thanks for your comment, I have provided a little more context around the requirement for a mutable mutex in the top snippet of code, including the Default implementation, and the Windows crate API for registering the mutex, requiring a *mut FAST_MUTEX. Further down the post I have added towards an MRE, but given the codebase and getting a driver setup, I'm not sure i could provide a full MRE in this context

What does add_process_creation_to_queue look like?

@Luke Hey! I have added add_process_creation_to_queue and add_message_to_queue to the above impl block; essentially they add an element of either String or ProcessStarted to the data field of self. I have included the struct also for ProcessStarted

I'm not well versed in Rust but from a Windows kernel perspective nothing looks out of place. What does the crash dump look like?
